# Drupal single sign on local

Tags: nodes

Is it possible to test signle sign from active directory on locally on your desktop?

Does it work with XAMPP / IIS?

Comment: Why wouldn't work for XAMPP/ISS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can test it against any Active Directory you can connect to.

But if you want a local copy of active directory, you can install a local copy of [Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS) for Windows7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14683) or equivalent.

Once installed, you will also need to configure to work with drupal's [ldap](https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap) module as normal. Then you will be able to work locally.

I have done this using XAMPP on a windows laptop.